# CryptographicException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, encryption

While Decrypting Key I am getting error :

> CryptographicException was unhandled by user code.
>   Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

Now what I want to do is, I want to check whether the given string is able to decrypt or not. If it is able to decrypt than only I want to execute below code. So that I cannot get an error.

```
var byteBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
var strDecrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                   objDesCrypto.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
```

Is there any way to check it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solution. Have to check for valid base64 string :

```
if ((value.Length % 4 == 0) && Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,3}$", RegexOptions.None))
{
    var byteBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
    decryptedString =
        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            objDesCrypto.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a followed question could be: if it is not able to decrypt, what does your code want to do. Anyway with that considered, you can always use try...catch like:

```
try { /* your code */ }
catch (CryptographicException e) { /* whatever you need to if it is not able to */ }
```

Comment: I am already using try catch block. and in try catch blog we generate exeception log and send an email. this is what I don't want. and because of this it has become necessary to check whether string is valid base64 string or not.

Comment: I have found the solution for the same and updated question with solution. By the way thanks for your suggestion. :)